# Control a trigger using when clause in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers, database-trigger

I am trying to create trigger `TRIG_USER` in Oracle db. Is there a way to control this trigger using the when clause.I want the trigger to activate only if there a entry in the table *trigger_switch*

I am looking something like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIG_USER
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON USER_TABLE 
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM trigger_switch))
BEGIN 
[...]
END;
```

Comment: oracle or mysql ???

Comment: Oracle.. Db.....

Comment: then why is tagged  mysql ???  remove the wrong tag

Comment: Why not simply enabling/disabling the trigger itself?

Comment: What are you using the trigger_switch table for? If it's to decide whether to allow a trigger to run or not, you could maybe use that table to populate a context and then use that context in the when clause of your trigger.

Comment: `WHEN` clause isn't meant to be that flexible. Such a feature may come in the future versions, but currently that degree of control can only be exercised from within the Trigger body.

Comment: you just need to shift this part into your trigger body - WHEN (IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM trigger_switch))   - the way you are trying is not available

Comment: @AshishShetkar I image that the OP wants to do the check in the when clause, because it's faster than having the check in the body - at least, according to my tests (with both a bulk insert and row-by-row insert of a million rows)